# XpathResultMatchers xpath - find element by class attribute

Tags: html, unit-testing, xpath, mocking, spring-boot-test

I use MoskMvc to test the SpringBoot web-application; as a result, it is necessary to find an element on resulted html-page by class, but I can notю By id, find it without problems.

Sample of html:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 py-2" data-id="10">
    <div class="card h-100 my-3 border border-info rounded">
        <p class="card-header text-muted">
                <a class="btn" href="/user-messages/1?message=10">10</a>
        </p>
        <div class="card-body m-2">
            <p class="card-text text">test text</p>
            <p class="card-text tag">#testtag</p>
        </div>
        <p class="card-footer text-muted">
            <a href="/user-messages/1">admin</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This part of code is good:

```
.andExpect(xpath("//div[@id='message-list']/div[@data-id=10]/div/p").exists());
```

But this code can't find element

```
.andExpect(xpath("//div[@id='message-list']/div[@data-id=10]/div/p[@class=\"card-text text\"]").exists());
```

with error message

```
java.lang.AssertionError: XPath //div[@id='message-list']/div[@data-id=10]/div/p[@class="card-text text"] does not exist
```

where am I wrong?

Comment: is any reason you use `\` while checking `@class` value in `p[@class=\"card-text text\"]"` update like `p[@class='card-text text']"' then try once

Comment: It did not help...

Answer (score 0):

Check this once hope will help:

```
.andExpect(xpath("//div[@id='message-list']/div[@data-id=10]/div/p[@class='card-text text']").exists());
```